# Start matlab with a file and additional arguments

Tags: matlab

I want to start matlab like any normal executable like this

`matlab /path/to/some/mat_file.m argument1 argument2`

apparently matlab does not play like normal executables and will just ignore my request, but you can pass it commands to evaluate after startupt like

`matlab -r "disp('hi');"`

but this does not help, I can use the run-command to run the mat_file.m, but I can not pass additional arguments to run so argument1 and argument2 won't be present.

I can't see a way to bring matlab to behave that way.

NOTE: I will not use cd in the -r part. There is a reason that I am in the directory that I am currently in and I won't move out.

Comment: @AnderBiguri run('/path/to/some/mat_file.m', 1, 2); Error using run
Too many input arguments.

Comment: The title of the question is not quite accurate. It is more about the file path, rather than arguments. You can modify it to make it more accurate

Comment: @XiangruiLi if it was just a file-path-problem, then -r "run('/path/...');" would have been enough. But maybe I don't understand what exactly you mean. Can you maybe suggest a different title?

Comment: I would suggest something like "Start matlab with an m file not in matlab path"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two possible solutions. First, you can add and save path of your directory for matlab, then start your function like

```
matlab -r "my_file(in1, in2)"
```

Second, if you don't like to save the path, you can `addpath` in the command line, like

```
matlab -r "addpath('/path/to/some'); my_file(in1, in2)"
```